# raywenderlich tutorial - simple iphone game - part2

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am using the second part of the [iphone games tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/25791/rotating-turrets-how-to-make-a-simple-iphone-game-with-cocos2d-2-x-part-2), and I am confused about the `ccTouchesEnded` method's implementation. It is where the 'shooting' is implemented: the player (a cannon) is turned to the touched direction, and the projectile is shot.
The part that's unclear to me is: `_nextProjectile` seems to be released while it could still be in use (by the code right below it - `_nextProjectile runAction`).
Could you please explain why is it safe to release the object at this point?

```
- (void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

[_player runAction:

 [CCSequence actions:

  [CCRotateTo actionWithDuration:rotateDuration angle:cocosAngle],

  [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{

     // OK to add now - rotation is finished!

     [self addChild:_nextProjectile];

     [_projectiles addObject:_nextProjectile];



     // Release

     [_nextProjectile release];

     _nextProjectile = nil;

 }],

  nil]];



// Move projectile to actual endpoint

[_nextProjectile runAction:

 [CCSequence actions:

  [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:realMoveDuration position:realDest],

  [CCCallBlockN actionWithBlock:^(CCNode *node) {

     [_projectiles removeObject:node];

     [node removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];

 }],

  nil]];



}
```

Comment: I think this is a question about blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Earlier on in *ccTouchesEnded:withEvent:* you increased the retain count of **_nextProjectile** on this line:

```
_nextProjectile = [[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"projectile2.png"] retain];
```

So at some point later on you have to decrease the retain count to prevent a memory leak. In other words: you are responsable for releasing this retain. That is where this line is coming from:

```
[_nextProjectile release];
```

Why is it safe to release it at that point? The pieces of code you posted in your question are both actually actions in a sequence of actions.

```
[_player runAction:[CCSequence actions:...]];
```

Performing an action on an object increases the retain count on that object. This means the action object itself creates and holds another reference to **_nextProjectile**. The sequence of actions is created before the actions are actually performed, hence the action object already has its own reference to **_nextProjectile**. So releasing it in one of the actions is actually safe. They waited with releasing **_nextProjectile** until these lines passed:

```
[self addChild:_nextProjectile];
[_projectiles addObject:_nextProjectile];
```

A release before these lines would probably (I haven't looked at any other code than *ccTouchesEnded:withEvent:*) result in a EXC_BAD_ACCESS runtime error.

Here is some more info about the retain count: [cocos2d forum](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forums/topic/cleanup-help-me-understand/)